# Difference between Archive destination & db_recovery_file_dest

Tags: oracle, recovery, archive-log

What is exact difference between Archive destination & db_recovery_file_dest on Oracle Database?

```
SQL> show parameter reco

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_file_record_keep_time        integer     7
db_recovery_file_dest                string      C:\app\Azar\fast_recovery_area
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 6930M
db_unrecoverable_scn_tracking        boolean     TRUE
recovery_parallelism                 integer     0


SQL> archive log list
Database log mode              No Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Disabled
Archive destination            C:\app\Azar\Arch
Oldest online log sequence     320
Current log sequence           322
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive log destination define the place where to store archived redo log files(once online redo log file is filled it can be stored as archived log files). You can have multiple archive log destinations.

In other hand, `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST` specifies the default location for the fast recovery area. The fast recovery area contains multiplexed copies of current control files and online redo logs, as well as archived redo logs, flashback logs, and RMAN backups.

You can use `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`(which is default if you enable archive log mode in your database without specifying archive log destination explicitly), which is fast recovery area, to store archived redo log files or you can store them in separate locations.

**Documentation:**

[DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-A137E048-DFBA-49D8-97F2-3A657F4FD84C.htm#REFRN10234)

[Managing Archived Redo Log Files](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/archredo.htm#ADMIN008)

Comment: Thanks !.Then online redo log and Archived redo log i.e offline redo log will be stored in same location ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Generally, online redo log files are stored in the location where data files and control files are stored. You can choose where to store these files.

Comment: So, it seems offline redo log is important than online redo log files. is it?

Comment: Both are important, online redo log is most crucial as these are used to store transaction log, database can not function in case of these are unavailable. Archived redo logs are optional, if you wish to perform point-in-time recovery, then you need these files.

Comment: I've been working with Oracle for over 20 years and this is the first time I've heard archivelogs referred to as "offline redo logs".  Just sayin' . . .   As for comments about what "is" in the FRA, that needs to be qualified.  The FRA _may_ contain a copy of the redo logs, it _may_ contain a copy of the control file, and it _may_ contain archivelogs.  Nothing says it _has_ to be used for everything that it _may_ be used for.